# Transaction is included into the block but reverted

Tags: tokens, raw-transaction

I'm trying to send USDT token (1.234567 USDT) from my wallet with this code:

```
>>> from web3 import Web3
>>> 
>>> INFURA_URL = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<infura id>"
>>> PRIVATE_KEY = b'<some private key>'
>>> web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(INFURA_URL))
>>> 
>>> my_account = web3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY)
>>> receiver_address = "0x3Aa124E916C920ff30f7E236092C7a41e95bA1eF"
>>> usdt_abi = [{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_upgradedAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"deprecate","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"deprecated","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_evilUser","type":"address"}],"name":"addBlackList","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"upgradedAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balances","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"maximumFee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"_totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"_maker","type":"address"}],"name":"getBlackListStatus","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"who","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"newBasisPoints","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newMaxFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setParams","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"issue","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"redeem","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"basisPointsRate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"isBlackListed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_clearedUser","type":"address"}],"name":"removeBlackList","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":True,"inputs":[],"name":"MAX_UINT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":False,"inputs":[{"name":"_blackListedUser","type":"address"}],"name":"destroyBlackFunds","outputs":[],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"name":"_decimals","type":"uint256"}],"payable":False,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Issue","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Redeem","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"Deprecate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"name":"feeBasisPoints","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":False,"name":"maxFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Params","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"name":"_blackListedUser","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"name":"_balance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DestroyedBlackFunds","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"AddedBlackList","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":False,"name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"RemovedBlackList","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[{"indexed":True,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":True,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":False,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":False,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"}];
>>> contract_address="0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"
>>> 
>>> contract = web3.eth.contract(contract_address, abi=usdt_abi)
>>> print(f"My balance: {contract.functions.balanceOf(my_account.address).call()}")
My balance: 18000000
>>> print(f"Receiver balance: {contract.functions.balanceOf(receiver_address).call()}")
Receiver balance: 0
>>> 
>>> raw_txn = {
...     "from":my_account.address,
...     "gasPrice": web3.eth.gasPrice,
...     "gas":300000,
...     "to":contract_address,
...     "value":"0x0",
...     "data":contract.functions.transfer(receiver_address, 1234567).selector,
...     "nonce":web3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_account.address)
... }
>>> 
>>> signed_txn = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(raw_txn, PRIVATE_KEY)
>>> web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
HexBytes('0x90a4462b6f41d96ddaaed9e584ae8c41363122f61ff741fb0f52ff4ff4af47eb')
>>> 
>>> print(f"My balance: {contract.functions.balanceOf(my_account.address).call()}")
My balance: 18000000
>>> print(f"Receiver balance: {contract.functions.balanceOf(receiver_address).call()}")
Receiver balance: 0
```

Then I found my transaction here: https://www.blockchain.com/eth/tx/0xa550c16eb6a199bc8baf41263d939e8050608dca283a5573e779c8de614d90b7 but it's reverted. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: You're probably wrong in `data":contract.functions.transfer(receiver_address, 1234567).selector`. It shouldn't be selector, but `encodedABI()` or something similar. It shows pretty clear on etherscan - you've sent only the function selector (first 8 bytes in the hash of the function signature). You should have sent that along with the (ABI-encoded) input parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
"data": contract.functions.transfer(receiver_address, 1234567).selector
```

You are sending only the function selector (the first 4 bytes in the hash of the function signature).

You should send that along with the (ABI-encoded) input parameter values, which you can do with:

```
"data": contract.encodeABI("transfer", args = (receiver_address, 1234567))
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I get a `nonce too low` error. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: @Vassily: Include `"nonce"` field in your transaction, and set it to the correct value (your account's current nonce).

Comment: But it's included already :/ `"nonce":web3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_account.address)`

Comment: @Vassily: Maybe try to reconnect to the node or something. Or even get rid of it, and let the node determine the `nonce` by itself.

Comment: It worked! Correct value for `data` is `contract.encodeABI('transfer', args=(receiver_address, 1234567))`

Comment: @Vassily: Yup, I wrote the above answer with my web3.js knowledge (though I later noticed that I've mixed your web3.py syntax into it).

Comment: Anyway, you're my hero of the day! Can I buy a coffee for you?

Comment: @Vassily: hahaha, sure, but all coffee shops are currently closed, so it will have to wait ;)

Comment: just give me your usdt address :)